# Stripping a string of its non-numeric characters

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a phone number stored in `$phone`, it looks like this: `(555) 555-5555`. I want it to look like this: `5555555555`. How do I take the string and strip it of hyphens, spaces, and parenthesis?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

With a [regexp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php). Specifically, use the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) function:

```
$phone = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phone);
```

Answer (score 27):

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
```

Comment: perfect - cleans '(555).555-55.55' to '5555555555'

Answer (score 3):

Cumbersome method for regex avoiders:

```
implode(array_filter(str_split('(555) 555-5555'), 'is_numeric'));
```

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1

Another option is to simply use the `preg_match_all` with a simple expression:

```
[0-9]+
```

#### Test

```
$phone_number_inputs = ['(555) 555-5555', '(444) 444 4444', '333-333-3333', '1-222-222-2222', '1 (888) 888-8888', '1 (777) 777-7777',
    '11111(555) 555-5555'];

$phone_number_outputs = [];
foreach ($phone_number_inputs as $str) {
    preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $str, $numbers, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        $phone_number .= $number[0];
    }

    if (strlen($phone_number) == 10 || strlen($phone_number) == 11) {
        array_push($phone_number_outputs, $phone_number);
        print(" " . $phone_number . " may be a phone number! \n");
    } else {
        print(" " . $phone_number . " may not be a phone number! \n");
    }
    $phone_number = null;
}

var_export($phone_number_outputs);
```

#### Output

```
 5555555555 may be a phone number! 
 4444444444 may be a phone number! 
 3333333333 may be a phone number! 
 12222222222 may be a phone number! 
 18888888888 may be a phone number! 
 17777777777 may be a phone number! 
 111115555555555 may not be a phone number!
```

and `var_export($phone_number_outputs);` would print:

```
array (
  0 => '5555555555',
  1 => '4444444444',
  2 => '3333333333',
  3 => '12222222222',
  4 => '18888888888',
  5 => '17777777777',
)
```

### Method 2

It would be best to find solutions similar to method 1.

However, we can also design some more complicated expressions depending on the inputs that we might have, such as with:

```
^(?:[0-9][- ])?\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[- ][0-9]{3}[- ][0-9]{4}$
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uOsZTE/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/uOsZTE/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]