# PHP - remove all non-numeric characters from a string

Tags: php, string

What is the best way for me to do this? Should I use regex or is there another in-built PHP function I can use?

For example, I'd want: `12 months` to become `12`. `Every 6 months` to become `6`, `1M` to become `1`, etc.

Comment: @mickmackusa Why not [Stripping a phone number of its parenthesis, spaces, and hyphens in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5109538/3832970) I do not think this question should be deleted BTW.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) in this case;

```
$res = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", "Every 6 Months" );
```

$res return 6 in this case.

If want also to include decimal separator or thousand separator check this example:

```
$res = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", "$ 123.099");
```

$res returns "123.099" in this case

Include period as decimal separator or thousand separator: "/[^0-9.]/"

Include coma as decimal separator or thousand separator: "/[^0-9,]/"

Include period and coma as decimal separator and thousand separator: "/[^0-9,.]/"

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, is it possible to also explode a string with multiple delimiters? So basically allow `explode()` to work on either a comma, a semi-colon, a colon, etc?

Comment: hm, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955433/php-multiple-delimiters-in-explode

Comment: The provided answer allows the string keep commas and periods. The question asks to remove all non-numeric characters. It's a minor edit (doesn't quite qualify for editing since it's only 2 characters), but the answer to remove all non numeric should be `$res = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", "Every 6 Months" );`

Comment: Negative numbers * exist * , then $res = preg_replace("/[^0-9.-]/", "", "$ -123.099");

Answer (score 76):

Use `\D` to match non-digit characters.

```
preg_replace('~\D~', '', $str);
```

Comment: Removes periods as well. Which might be what some are looking for.

Comment: And it removes spaces/newlines, which is exactly what some are looking for :)

Comment: Also the simplest, which is what I am looking for