# Remove all non-numeric characters from a string in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove all non-numeric characters from a string.
This is the string:

```
$price = '₪1,180.00';
```

*(the first character is the new israeli shekel currency symbol)*

I tried to use:

```
$price_numeric_value = preg_replace( '/\D/', '', $price );
echo '<pre>';var_dump( $price_numeric_value );echo '</pre>';

$price_numeric_value = preg_replace( '~\D~', '', $price );
echo '<pre>';var_dump( $price_numeric_value );echo '</pre>';

$price_numeric_value = preg_replace( '/[^0-9.]/', '', $price );
echo '<pre>';var_dump( $price_numeric_value );echo '</pre>';
```

As suggested in these posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34399544/4711865
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33993704/4711865

The output i'm getting is this:

```
string(10) "8362118000"
```

Any idea why?

EDIT: I'm running this code on a Wordpress website, the php file is encoded in utf-8 and adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` doesn't help.

Comment: `preg_replace( '/\D/', '', $price );` returns `118000`, see https://ideone.com/M7DF2Q

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey, I see the link you sent, is it possible that the preg_replace function that is running on my site is affected by something? i'm running this on Wordpress inside a template file.

Comment: Check the UTF8 encoding of the files. Try `preg_replace( '/\D+/u', '', $price );`, too.

Comment: Even if the file is Ascii encoded the result of `preg_replace( '/\D/', '', $price );` is  118000

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Same result, the file is encoded in utf-8 and I even tried with `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`, same result. :/

Comment: Are you sure there is no other interfering code somewhere on the way from `$price = '₪1,180.00';` to `preg_replace( '/\D/', '', $price )`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes! I literally place them one below the other... that's the reason I posted this, somehow the value is being mixed up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`8362` is the numeric part of the html entity for the New Sheqel Sign `&#8362;`, when you remove all non numeric you got `8362` just before the value.

You have to [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) the string before preg_replace.

```
$price_numeric_value = preg_replace( '/\D/', '', html_entity_decode($price) );
echo $price_numeric_value;
```