# how to clean/sanitize a number with different international formats in PHP?

Tags: php, format

i have different strings in PHP representing numbers. i am looking for a function to convert them to  MYSQL compatible numbers ('4209.99'), regardeless of their international formatting.

```
    $test_number= "$4,209.99";
    $test_number= "$4209.99";
    $test_number= "$4209,99";
    $test_number= "4209,99";
    $test_number= "4209.99"; // the right format
```

Comment: Will all the strings(numbers) have 2 decimal and a separator before them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all non-numeric characters from a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283229/remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-php)

Comment: this is not a duplicate. Need to handle decimals which is not the case in the proposed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always have 2 decimal numbers,
you could remove all non-digits and divide by 100.

```
$nums = [
    "4209",
    "4209 EUR",
    "$4,209.99",
    "$4209.99",
    "$4209,99",
    "4209,99",
    "4209.99",
    "4209.00",
    "4209,00",
];

foreach($nums as $num) {
    if(preg_match('/([\.\,]*)(\d{2})(\D*)$/', $num, $matches))
    {
        $num = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $num);
        if($matches[1]) $num /= 100;
    }
    echo $num, PHP_EOL;
}
```

> 4209
>
> 4209
>
> 4209.99
>
> 4209.99
>
> 4209.99
>
> 4209.99
>
> 4209.99
>
> 4209
>
> 4209

**Update**
Now it maches more test cases and divides by 100 only if a seperator is there.

Comment: good answer but you are right to ask, might have '4209' without decimals that can become '42.09'....

Comment: @RenaudDUGERT Updated answer to pass more tests

Comment: Congrats ! Perfect answer Markus.